# Equality of reference types in template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, reference, non-type-template-parameter

The C++ standard says in [[temp.type]#2.7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.type#2.7), that

> Two values are *template-argument-equivalent* if they are of the same type and
> ...
> (2.7) they are of reference type and they refer to the same object or function

This is different, than how reference types are compared in non-template code. Say e.g.

```
template <auto& x1, auto& x2>
constexpr bool equal_tmpl = false;

template <auto& x>
constexpr bool equal_tmpl<x, x> = true;
```

and

```
consteval bool equal_fun(auto& x1, auto& x2)
{
    return x1 == x2;
}
```

mean different things. `equal_tmpl` compares the addresses, but `equal_fun` compares the values:

```
constexpr int i = 123;
constexpr int j = 123;

static_assert(equal_tmpl<i, j> != equal_fun(i, j));
```

Why is this defined this way in the standard? Souldn't equality in templates work the same way as in non-template code? [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/d38GsofcK).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the purposes of template argument equivalence, the question we want to be asking is "are these two arguments *identical*?" rather than "are these two arguments *equal*?"

References to two different variables that have the same value might be *equal* to each other, but they aren't identical: one may not be substituted for the other. Imagine if we had this:

```
template <const int& r>
constexpr auto foo() { return &r; }
```

Would it make any sense if the standard said that `foo<i>` and `foo<j>` are the same function because `i == j` (where `i` and `j` are defined as in the question)? No. `foo<i>` is a function that returns the address of `i`, and `foo<j>` is a function that returns the address of `j`, and those two addresses aren't the same.